# How can I pass a filename from an environment variable to sed in cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

In my Cygwin XP console, I can run:

```
$ sed -i "s/font*=.*/font=TT DejaVu Sans Mono/g" "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/etc/Rconsole"
```

However, when I set a variable:

```
sanya@ligong-a691b08a ~
$ fname="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/etc/Rconsole"
```

I get an error when I run this:

```
sanya@ligong-a691b08a ~
$ sed -i "s/font*=.*/font=TT DejaVu Sans Mono/g"   $fname
sed：can't read /cygdrive/c/Program：No such file or directory
sed：can't read Files/R/R-3.0.2/etc/Rconsole：No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote filenames with spaces:

```
sed -i "s/font*=.*/font=TT DejaVu Sans Mono/g" "$fname"
```